# jQuery function to detect non-empty input and display input clear button

Tags: jquery

[image]

I have existing code which displays input-clear button at the end of an input #q when user fills in and disappear the button when the input becomes empty:

```
$(document).on('propertychange keyup input paste pageinit', '#q', function(){
    var io = $(this).val().length ? 1 : 0 ;
    $(this).next('.icon_clear').stop().fadeTo(0,io);
}).on('click', '.icon_clear', function() {
    $(this).delay(0).fadeTo(0,0).prev('input').val('').focus();
});
```

Portion of index.php:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="" class="search-box" method="POST">
<span class="clearable">
<input type="text" name="q" id="q" size="22" value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>" autocomplete="off" maxlength="1024" class="search" placeholder="Search" >
<span class="icon_clear">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</span>
</form>
```

[An example of jquery input-clear button](http://jsfiddle.net/PJZmv/801/)

The problem is that: when user key in some text and press enter, index.php?q=text is called. Then the input-clear button is not displayed since there is no occurrence of any event on input #q (though #q contain text value as per `value="<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>"` ). Because #q contain value, naturally, input-clear button is expected.

**How can I update the script so that input-clear button is shown as long as there is value in input #q.**

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to trigger a change event to check the input on a page-refresh from a user submitting with the enter key, correct?

Comment: bind an jquery function onto pageload or just on the value instead of the whole document.

Comment: @tymeJV: correct. up on page refresh, value is kept in input, so I want to clear-text button to be shown but in current script, it is not.

Comment: @codelio: could you please be specific with a working example. I am new to javascript, might not be able to implement your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean when page init, let it check is it need a clear button ? this should work

http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/PJZmv/1404/

```
$('input.data_field').trigger('input');
```

Comment: Thank you Wing Leong. The example look good. But id=q is used to declare the input in my actual code, I have tried to put in $("#q").trigger("#q") but it does not work. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: You should use `$('#q').trigger('input')`, here `input` is an event

Answer (score 1):

This solution is specific to HTML5 supported browsers (mainly Chrome), but you can include `type="search"` to have an "X" automatically appended to the end of the input box as long as there's content.

```
<input type="search"/>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3mcJ8/

Magic.